# Save opened files in Preview as reading list

Tags: macos, preview

I am a researcher and I have to keep open multiple sets of PDFs pertaining to different projects. I generally use one window per project with tabbed PDFs.

Is there any way to export the reading list in a given Preview window to reopen it on demand? Ideally I would like to click on a file that opens in a single window all the PDFs related to a given project.

I don't want alternatives using different Desktops, Safari, etc.

Comment: I'm sure this could be accomplished through some clever scripting for the `Preview` app, but are you aware that when you log off or shut down you're presented with an option to **"Reopen windows..."**?